# Where stores V-DOM in js frameworks

Tags: reactjs, angular, vue.js

In my previous work-interview i had ask about storing VDOM but i didnt get a answer on this question and nothing found in internet so can anyone explain how are vdom storing in web browser

only thing i know is vdom is storing in browser memory but is that correct?
thank you very much for answer

Comment: Virtual DOM itself is not stored in the browser, the resulting changes made to the real DOM are stored and managed by the browser.